# Reviewing new questions: off-topic: GIS

Tags: discussion, review, migration

I've just been reviewing new questions and came across this one:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts#first-posts/4227099?&_suid=139393209442503262426903344138

I tried to flag that it should be migrated to https://gis.stackexchange.com/ but the option wasn't there (only other stackexchange sites like Server Fault, Super User etc were listed).

Did I go about this the wrong way, or would it be sensible to have a list of all stackexchange sites on the off-topic list?

Comment: @devnull Thanks for that!  Next time I'll flag it for mod attention.